# Deeplink showing error in safari when the app is not installed in the iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deeplink

I am working on an app, and i am facing an issue. When some one clicks on the deep link url in the sms(deeplink_sms.PNG), if the app is installed everything works fine(screen shot 1.PNG). But if the app is not installed the safari is showing an error message(screen shot 2.PNG). Can some one help me with this?
enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a webpage that has javascript on it to handle opening your app link. Then, instead of sending your app link via SMS, send the link to your webpage.

1. User receives SMS with webpage link
2. User clicks link and Safari opens
3. Webpage detects its an iPhone and redirects to app link
4. You handle here if the app isn't installed e.g. show a "Please download the app" message